# Hubspot Form: There was an error when running your onFormReady function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hubspot-crm

I was embedding a hubspot form to my wordpress website and I need to run a piece of script when the form is loaded. This is the requirement, but I ran into an error and it showed like the following in the console.

[Hubspot Form: There was an error when running your onFormReady function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlhqS.png)

My hubspot code is :

```
<script>
 hbspt.forms.create({
            region: "xxxxx",
            portalId: "xxxxxxx",
            formId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            onFormSubmit: function($form) {
                console.log("form is submitted already");             
                //some other stuff as well
                jQuery('.hubspot_form_outer_class').hide();
            },
            onFormReady: function($form) {
                console.log("success");
                $("div.input > select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
</script>
```

Here `onFormSubmit` function works fine(no problem with the jQuery script in it as well), but the function `onFormReady` doesnot work. I just need to make this function work.
What is the issue here? Anyone has an idea? Any help/information is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update:** Console output for `jQuery("div.input > select");`

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaWnO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with this line of code

```
$("div.input > select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Try changing that to

```
jQuery("div.input > select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Also make sure you include jQuery on the page where this script is running.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I don't know what happened, I haven't checked back the code for long, however the console message is actually displaying... I meant "success" is displaying, but the select is not getting disabled. The attribute path is correct.